# What is the proper way to target the tab key 'highlight' events on an html element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand how to  respond to tab key navigation, but am not sure which event is triggered when an element receives focus via  the tab key .

In the code linked to below, I want all the buttons to grow to full size when the user tabs over any of them.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YopBaz

In the example, I have the effect working with the mouse ':hover' psuedo class, but am not sure how to achieve the same effect for the tab highlighted event. I've tried watching for all ( active/ focus / hover ) events on the parent div element when the tab selection is focused on any one of it's child elements. This hasn't worked for me, so I'm wondering is there an event that perhaps bubbles up to the parent of the element highlighted with 'tab' selection?

The relevant css is:

```
 .speed-unit-selector .btn.active, .speed-unit-selector .btn:hover, .speed-unit-selector:active .btn,
.speed-unit-selector:hover .btn,
.speed-unit-selector:focus .btn {
  transform: scale(1, 1);
}
```

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 6):

The `tab` key navigation triggers the `:focus` event on the elements. You can also change the order in which the elements are 'focused' with `tabindex="value"` attribute.

Keep in mind that `tab` key won't focus on elements which do not support `:focus` event and also don't have a `tabindex` attribute set. For e.g if you want to be able to focus on a `p` element, add a `tabindex` to it.

see below

```css
button:focus {
  background: red;
}
p:focus {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<button tabindex="1">
BUtton
</button>
<button tabindex="3">
BUtton    
</button>
<button tabindex="2">
BUtton
</button>


<p tabindex="4">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</p>
```

Comment: yes, you cannot select elements with `tab` if that element doesn't support focus or it doesn't have tabindex attribute set. I will  add that to my answer :).

Comment: I read that using a tab index greater than 0 is anti-pattern, other than that you suggestion works for me!

Comment: antipattern because the users are used for the tabs to go in a certain order. But i just said that you have this option if you need to use it for some reason. It was just a ' bonus ' detail that has nothing to do with the solution itself

Comment: If this answer solved your problem please rate it as accepted. Thanks ! :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your code it will work.

```
.speed-unit-selector .btn:focus{
  transform: scale(1, 1) !important;
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;  
  opacity: 1;
}
```